# How to get a higher-resolution version of the image that is used for image analysis in CameraX

Tags: android-camerax

I'm using the [TensorFlow Lite Object Detection Android example application](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) as a starting point. This uses the CameraX library's image analysis approach do object detection on what the camera sees. (It also displays a preview of what the camera sees on the phone's screen.)

That application uses a 640x480 image for analysis. Here's the code that sets-up the preview and connects the image to the analyzer:

```
    // Preview. Only using the 4:3 ratio because this is the closest to our models
    preview =
        Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
            .build()

    // ImageAnalysis. Using RGBA 8888 to match how our models work
    imageAnalyzer =
        ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
            .setTargetRotation(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .setOutputImageFormat(OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
            .build()
            // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
            .also {
                it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor) { image ->
                    if (!::bitmapBuffer.isInitialized) {
                        // The image rotation and RGB image buffer are initialized only once
                        // the analyzer has started running
                        bitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                          image.width,
                          image.height,
                          Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                        )
                    }

                    detectObjects(image)
                }
            }
```

([Link to relevant part of the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/objectdetection/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L236).)

I need to extract parts of the image when they are detected. The problem is the image object that is passed to detector ([here in the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/objectdetection/ObjectDetectorHelper.kt#L105)) is just 640x480 - it's too low-resolution to get close-up details:

[image]

How can I get access to a higher-resolution image from the camera, when I need it? For object detection, I assume I need to keep the low-res image for performance (and because of the way the object detection is trained) but I imagine there must be a way to pull a higher-quality image when a match is found. I can't find anywhere in the codebase where the resolution is being set (searched for 640 and 480 and "resolution").

I know I can bump up the analysis resolution by changing this line:

```
.setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
```

... to an explicit resolution, like this:

```
.setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 960))
```

But I assume that's not the right way to go, as performance will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to bump up the resolution of a stream on request. You can use a higher resolution for ImageAnalysis. The performance will suffer but I doubt it would be too much. Or, you can take a photo with ImageCapture which can give you the max resolution. However taking a photo is relatively high latency so you may not get the same frame as the ImageAnalysis.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a few different things, and then settled on passing a higher image size to the imageAnalzyer but then scaling it back down to 640x480 before passing it to the image detector itself. That resulted in OK performance, while giving me the higher-resolution image I needed.